# Looking for clarification on how escaping (slashes) works in wpdb and best practice

Tags: wordpress

I'm just after fixing the output of some of my code to remove slashes from strings stored in and retrieved from the database using `wpdb` functions. Then I expected to have to fix the same issue in another section of my code where strings are stored in and retrieved from the database but noticed that no slashes were added so I'm a bit confused about when slashes are added automatically. Here are my observations from these 2 cases that I encountered:

**Case 1** - I needed to strip slashes on output

1. `$_POST` data is automatically escaped with slashes
2. by using `$wpdb->insert` and `$wpdb->update` data ends up WITH slashes in database
3. data retrieved with `$wpdb->get_row` and `$wpdb->get_results` has slashes
4. I used stripslashes to resolve this issue

**Case 2** - I didn't need to strip slashes on output

1. `$_POST` data is automatically escaped with slashes
2. using `$wpdb->query` to insert and update data ends up WITHOUT slashes in database
3. data retrieved with `$wpdb->get_row` and `$wpdb->get_results` does not have slashes
4. no need to strip slashes on output

My questions are:

- Why is the behaviour different in these 2 cases?
- What is the best practice for dealing with escaping when using `wpdb` functions?
- If a string contains a single quote, should that quote be escaped in the database? (i.e. if you view it in PHPMyAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

From the codex:

> Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped). This means that if you are using GET or POST data you may need to use striplashes() to avoid slashes ending up in the database.

You may also want to take a look at this section: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks